# CRNA build:android issues

Tags: android, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I am trying to build an APK file for my CRNA project, using expo. The first issue is, it tries to build iOS every time. Why is it building iOS when I used `exp build:android`?
Second, iOS only succeeds in building occasionally. It usually hangs at 0%.

The output is below:

```
> exp build:android

[16:28:36] Making sure project is set up correctly...
-[16:28:38] Warning: Not using the Expo fork of react-native. See https://docs.expo.io/.
[16:28:38] Your project looks good!
[16:28:38] Checking if current build exists...

[16:28:39] No currently active or previous builds for this project.
[16:28:39] Unable to find an existing exp instance for this directory, starting a new one...
[16:28:40] Warning: Not using the Expo fork of react-native. See https://docs.expo.io/.
[16:28:42] Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
[16:28:42] Metro Bundler ready.
[16:28:43] Tunnel ready.
[16:28:43] Publishing to channel 'default'...
[16:28:44] Warning: Not using the Expo fork of react-native. See https://docs.expo.io/.
[16:28:44] Building iOS bundle
```

And then it hanngs indefinitely.
Has anyone came across any of these issues and have any advice?

My `app.json` is below

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
    "icon": "./test-icon.png",
    "entryPoint": "./AppEntry.js",
    "ignoreNodeModulesValidation": true,
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "rn-cli.config.js",
      "projectRoots": ""
    },
    "android":{
      "package": "expo.android.package",
    },
    "ios":{
      "bundleIdentifier": "expo.ios.package",
    },
  },
  "privacy": "unlisted",
  "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

expo version: 55.0.4

react-native version: 0.55.4

Comment: Got same problem